# ImageFile(path, Uri) to Base64 encoded string has problem in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, base64

I tried to capture camera preview in android device and encode imagefiles to Base64 String. I've already tested like this

```
// Convert Failed to Image
    private fun encoder1(filePath: File): String{
        val bytes = filePath.readBytes()
        val base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP)
        return base64
    }


    // Saved Broken Image
    private fun encoder2(imageUri: Uri): String {
        val input = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
        //val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.test)
        val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, null)
        //encode image to base64 string
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        //bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        image!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        var imageBytes = baos.toByteArray()

        return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP)
        //return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes) // Not Worked, too.
    }

    // Saved Broken Image
    private fun encoder3(path: String): String {
        val imagefile = File(path)
        var fis: FileInputStream? = null
        try {
            fis = FileInputStream(imagefile)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val b = baos.toByteArray()

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b)
    }
```

These encoder called like this

```
 override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    var photoPath = photoFile.canonicalPath
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    Log.e("Before Base64 encoder photoFile", photoFile.toString())
                    Log.d("Before Base64 encoder", savedUri.toString())
                    Log.d("Base64 encoder111", encoder1(photoFile))
                    Log.d("Base64 encoder222", encoder2(savedUri))
                    Log.d("Base64 encoder333", encoder3(photoPath))
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
```

and one of the base64 log/ is...

```
2020-09-01 15:14:16.485 5295-5295/com.soyeon.cameraxtutorial D/Base64 encoder222: 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
```

I printed Base64 String and ctrl+c/ ctrl+v in
https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter for check the results. But i only get broken images like
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eob8v.jpg

i think all the permission has included.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
```

saved images has no problems. HELP ME PLEASE!!!
https://github.com/paksuua/CameraXtutorial.git

Answer (score 0):

You should add the header like this [data:image/png;base64,]

You can try the image covert to base64 online

https://www.base64-image.de/

Check the base64 image data format

Comment: should i add this header [data:image/png;base64,] in Android kotlin...?? thanks for your reference. I've already converted image into base64 and vice versa. But still can't find the right solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you log the base64 string to logcat then only the first bytes of the string are printed.

So copy/paste will only give you part of the base64 string.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i could't solve this problem.. so try to find some other solution to send image from android to node server.