# How to send Image file use socket.io from android to node server?

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, file-io, socket.io

I tried to capture camera preview in android device and encode imagefiles to Base64 String. But it's not works. (
[ImageFile(path, Uri) to Base64 encoded string has problem in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682414/imagefilepath-uri-to-base64-encoded-string-has-problem-in-kotlin))

```
override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    var photoPath = photoFile.canonicalPath
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)                    
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }
```

and printed log like

```
2020-09-12 18:52:52.608 14880-14880/com.soyeon.cameraxtutorial D/CameraXBasic: Photo capture succeeded: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.soyeon.cameraxtutorial/CameraX%20Tutorial/2020-09-12-18-52-52-224.jpg
```

i clicked that log and dialog showed up.

```
Cannot find file file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.soyeon.cameraxtutorial/CameraX%20Tutorial/2020-09-12-18-52-52-224.jpg
```

But file all the permissions has been checked.

Also, checked file type error in arrived response encoded string.

If send Base64 string to server is not the right solution, please give me some other solution to send image use socket.io

Comment: .replace("%20", " ");

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work..

Comment: Once you have access to the file and do convert it to base64 string, a NodeJS server is easier to use JSON objects. You can send the base64 string as a JSON object. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject Also, I usually use absolutePath instead of your usage.